# Are multiple reduceByKey on the same RDD compiled into a single scan?

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose I have an RDD (50M records/dayredu) which I want to summarize in several different ways. 
The RDD records are 4-tuples: `(keep, foo, bar, baz)`.

- `keep` - boolean
- `foo`, `bar`, `baz` - 0/1 int

I want to count how many of each of the `foo` &c are kept and dropped, i.e., I have to do the following for `foo` (and the same for `bar` and `baz`):

```
rdd.filter(lambda keep, foo, bar, baz: foo == 1)
   .map(lambda keep, foo, bar, baz: keep, 1)
   .reduceByKey(operator.add)
```

which would return (after `collect`) a list like `[(True,40000000),(False,10000000)]`.

The question is: is there an ***easy*** way to avoid scanning `rdd` 3 times (once for each of `foo`, `bar`, `baz`)?

**What I mean is *not* a way to rewrite the above code to handle all 3 fields, but telling spark to process all 3 pipelines in a single pass.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to execute the three pipelines in parallel by submitting the job with different threads, but this will pass through the RDD three times and require up to 3x more resources on the cluster.

It's possible to get the job done in one pass by rewriting the job to handle all counts at once - the answer regarding `aggregate` is an option. Splitting the data in pairs `(keep, foo) (keep, bar), (keep, baz)` would be another.

It's **not possible** to get the job done in one pass without any code changes, as there would not be a way for Spark to know that those jobs relate to the same dataset. At most, the speed of subsequent jobs after the first one could be improved by `caching` the initial *rdd* with `rdd.cache`  before the `.filter().map().reduce()` steps; this will still pass through the RDD 3 times, but the 2nd and 3rd time will be potentially a lot faster if all data fits in the memory of the cluster:

```
rdd.cache
// first reduceByKey action will trigger the cache and rdd data will be kept in memory
val foo = rdd.filter(fooFilter).map(fooMap).reduceByKey(???)
// subsequent operations will execute faster as the rdd is now available in mem
val bar = rdd.filter(barFilter).map(barMap).reduceByKey(???)
val baz = rdd.filter(bazFilter).map(bazMap).reduceByKey(???)
```

If I were doing this, I would create pairs of the relevant data and count them in a single pass:

```
// We split the initial tuple into pairs keyed by the data type ("foo", "bar", "baz") and the keep information. dataPairs will contain data like: (("bar",true),1), (("foo",false),1)

val dataPairs = rdd.flatmap{case (keep, foo, bar, baz) => 
    def condPair(name:String, x:Int):Option[((String,Boolean), Int)] = if (x==1) Some(((name,keep),x)) else None
    Seq(condPair("foo",foo), condPair("bar",bar), condPair("baz",baz)).flatten
}
val totals = dataPairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

This is **easy** and will pass over the data only once, but requires rewriting of the code. I'd say it scores *66,66%* in answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want [RDD.aggregate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

```
val zeroValue = (0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L) // tfoo, tbar, tbaz, ffoo, fbar, fbaz
rdd.aggregate(zeroValue)(
  (prior, current) => if (current._1) {
    (prior._1 + current._2, prior._2 + current._3, prior._3 + current._4,
      prior._4, prior._5, prior._6)
  } else {
    (prior._1, prior._2, prior._3,
      prior._4 + current._2, prior._5 + current._3, prior._6 + current._4)
  },
  (left, right) =>
    (left._1 + right._1,
      left._2 + right._2,
      left._3 + right._3,
      left._4 + right._4,
      left._5 + right._5,
      left._6 + right._6)
)
```

Aggregate is conceptually like the conceptual reduce function on a list, but RDDs aren't lists, they're distributed, so you provide two function arguments, one to operate on each partition, and one to combine the results of processing the partitions.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is not a way to rewrite the above code to handle all 3 fields, but telling spark to process all 3 pipelines in a single pass.

Comment: AFAIK there is not. You can either create a merged pipeline in  single closure and run that in a single pass (same idea as this answer) or you can in some cases chain several transformations that will be executed as a single stage (single pass), but in that case, you still need to base every step in the previous one, so it is also not a clean way to achieve what you mention.

Comment: Spark actions are blocking calls, so there's no built-in way to parallelize three operations the way that you want to, or tell it to reuse the traversal you're already making. I have used threading to accomplish what you're describing, and it worked, but it doesn't seem to be an intended use of the framework, and an internal change to the RDD graph processing could easily break it. If you can achieve what you want with a relatively complicated aggregate() call, you'll be safer.